# How To Save Forms on PowerApps to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, pdf, powerapp

I am new to PowerApps. I have a sharepoint list that I would like to save information to from PowerApps.

On PowerApps, I want to display a PDF file for EXTERNAL USERS to scroll through and read, Name text box and email text box and accept or deny button. The accept button should save the information on the sharepoint list where I already have a flow that handles what happens next.

Please I have searched online on how to go about this but not getting it. I could get all objects on the form but could not load the exact pdf I want even though a sample pdf is on display. And could not save into the list.

Any help?

Comment: You can try https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/bd-p/PowerAppsForum1 site. You have a better chance of getting answers. But in any case, it's confusing as to what you are asking exactly. Maybe you can split your question into several smaller one. One about PDF, another about creating SharePoint list items.